# ¿Cómo convierto un número a letra en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero convertir tres columna de calificaciones a texto.

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| CALIFICACIÓN1 | CALIFICACIÓN2 | CALIFICACIÓN3 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|            10 |            10 |             8 |
|            10 |             8 |             5 |
|             8 |             7 |             5 |
|            10 |             7 |             5 |
|             7 |             8 |             5 |
|            10 |             6 |             7 |
|             5 |             9 |             5 |
|             8 |             6 |             8 |
|             5 |             6 |             9 |
|             8 |             5 |             9 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Es decir, que los 10 salgan en "A", los 9 en "B" y así sucesivamente ¿cómo se podría hacer?

Comment: como guardas esos datos? mas información ayuda a darte una respuesta mas certera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo a nivel de consulta con la declaración SQL `CASE`. En otras palabras funciona como un if - else pero a nivel de SQL.

Puedes leer más de la  CASE [ACÁ](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

**Ejemplo referencial**

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN your_column_name = 10 THEN 'A'
        WHEN your_column_name = 9 THEN 'B'
        WHEN your_column_name = 8 THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'score_error'
    END as SCORE_IN_LETTERS

FROM 
    your_table_name
```